# How to make password invisible in Swing text field?

Tags: java, swing, passwords, jtextfield, jpasswordfield

Can I make this password field hidden in Java Swing `JTextField`?

I want to set the password always to welcome as shown in below code but in hidden field. Is there an option by which I can achieve this in Java Swing?

```
jTextField_password.setBounds(new Rectangle(245, 25, 100, 25));
jTextField_password.setText("welcome");
```

Comment: Why not use JPasswordField ?

Comment: `..setBounds(new Rectangle(245, 25, 100, 25));`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  In this case, the size of a text field can also be changed by changing the number of columns displayed, or changing the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use  [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html). it's a subclass of JTextField that make text invisible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JPasswordField`. It's perfect for your case.
It's also much safer than a normal `Textfield`, because the `String` will be stored as a `char` array, which isn't in the normal `String` pool.